# Dagger Scope issue

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I am trying to set dagger up to provide a data module but I keep running into this error :

error: @Modules cannot be scoped. Did you mean to scope a method instead?
@javax.inject.Singleton()
^

Here is the culprit module :

```
package com.bottlerocket.dependancyinjection.modules


import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room
import com.bottlerocket.dependancyinjection.DI
import com.data.api.BottleRocketApi
import com.data.cache.StoreCache
import com.data.database.CacheDataStoreObject
import com.data.database.RemoteStoreDataObject
import com.data.database.StoreDatabase
import com.data.repository.StoreRepositoryImplementation
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import interfaces.StoresRepository
import javax.inject.Named
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@Singleton
class DataModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRoomDatabase(context: Context): StoreDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            StoreDatabase::class.java,
            "stores_db"
        ).build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideStoreRepository(
        api: BottleRocketApi,
        @Named(DI.inMemoryCache) cache: StoreCache
    ): StoresRepository {

        val cachedMoviesDataStore = CacheDataStoreObject(cache)
        val remoteMoviesDataStore = RemoteStoreDataObject(api)
        return StoreRepositoryImplementation(cachedMoviesDataStore, remoteMoviesDataStore)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, you can't annotate a module with `@Singleton`, only the functions. So all you have to do is remove the annotation from your module.

Change

```
@Module
@Singleton
class DataModule {
}
```

with

```
@Module
class DataModule {
}
```

This check was introduced in a recent version of Dagger.